# ComboBox ListItem Help

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, foreach

I have this code here, I am trying to output the contents of a combobox, to my label. But I get an error that I cannot convert char to System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem

```
     foreach (ListItem mine in ListSitesDropDownBox.Items)
      {
       Mylabel.Text += mine.Value.ToString() + " " + mine.ToString() + "<br>";
      }
```

How would you suggest I go about doing this so that I can output the value and name of the list item?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably not where the mentioned error is occurring. Are you sure this is the error message you're getting?

Comment: @BrunoBrant, I know weird, the only other place it could be coming from is combobox because this code is isolated and ive written this before. I dont know what could be causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `Text` property of mine in the second part.

```
  foreach (ListItem mine in ListSitesDropDownBox.Items)
  {
    Mylabel.Text += mine.Value + " " + mine.Text + "<br>";
  }
```

[Here's the MSDN reference for ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx). Also `ToString` is unnecessary for `Value` as it is already a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

why are you doing this:

```
ListSitesDropDownBox.ToString()
```

**???**

just replace it with:

```
ListSitesDropDownBox.Items
```

Comment: @DavidPiras Thanks I typed that wrong, I couldnt copy the code I had to rewrite when I posted it here so I must have added that wrong, but yes the correct version I had it the ".Items".